# How to deploy jms jar to Karaf

Tags: deployment, jar, karaf

I'm getting this error with Oracle jmscommon.jar but I this question could easily be extended to other non-OSGI bundle jars.
According to:

http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/operating-systems-and-server-administration/apache/9781782172048/5dot-deploying-applications/ch05s03_html

I should be able to drop just any jar to the Karaf deploy directory for the classes inside the jar to be available. However, when I try to deploy my app that references classes in jmscommon - it turns out these cannot be found.

Do I need to do install something in Karaf to be able to just drop any non-OSGI bundle jar in deploy? Or do I need to do something special for Oracle jmscommon.jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I just need to import the referenced packages in manifest.mf:
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework,javax.jms